# Transform rows into columns in MySql

Tags: php, html, mysql

i know this question has been asked on this platform but I couldn't get enough details to help me with my problem.

I have three tables I am selecting from: student, subjects and exam table.

student table:
[image]

Results Table
[image]

And the Subjects table:

[image]

If you take a look at the first table(results table) you will see the subjects codes. What I am trying to achieve is like the diagram below:

[image]

Here is my result table after I selected those results from database for **TS2018007**.

[image]

My query for image four:

```
SELECT distinct s.regiNo, s.firstName as fname, s.middleName as mname, s.lastName as lname, 
       s.gender, s.class_group, c.subjects,e.First_CA, e.Second_CA, e.examid, e.scored, 
       e.internaltype, e.Class, e.Year 
FROM student s inner join exam e on s.regiNo = e.Roll_Number 
     inner join subjects c on e.sub_id = c.subect_code 
group by s.regiNo, s.firstName, s.middleName, s.lastName, s.gender, s.class_group, 
         c.subjects, e.First_CA, e.Second_CA, e.examid, e.scored, e.internaltype, 
         e.Class, e.Year
```

How can I create an html table with dynamic rows and columns where row data relies on column heading everytime a new subject score is added to the exam table? I don't want hard code.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I would remove the PHP, it is really a mysql question

Comment: You'll need to use jquery and ajax to refresh the table content dynamically